# Close an issue via commit message

Tags: github, issue-tracking

The following keywords will close an issue via commit message:

- close
- closes
- closed
- fix
- fixes
- fixed
- resolve
- resolves
- resolved

What's the difference? When better to use close or fix?

Comment: Note that this is a GitHub feature, not part of Git itself; its only connection to Git is that GitHub is using Git to find the keywords. (This is why I am removing the `git` tag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it doesn't matter. If you use `Fix` as a mark for a commit that makes the issue go away, then use that. The same applies for the other keywords.

GitHub only gives you more options, because it tries to strip you of additional work e.g. finding issues the commit might be related to and manually close them and to do that it uses more keywords that could mean `close <issue>`.